# Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, proof, predicate-logic

How do I derive this?

Pr 1     ∀x(Fx -> ∀xGx)
∴        ∀x(Fx -> ∀x(Gx \ / Hx))

My attempt:

[image]

However I cannot used universal derivation due to the free x. I think using ass id and qn would be better option but I am unsure how to edit my proof so that I get the completed one.

I am using Elogic and this is list of rules:

[image]

Comment: What does it mean the "slash" symbol ?

Comment: Sorry it’s edited now

Comment: In the premise and conclusion, there are clashing variables. _x_ is a bound variable for both the outer and inner Universal Quantifiers.

Comment: You need only a couple of Universal Instantiation followed by a couple of Universal Generalization.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can you expand on what universal generalisation is please?

Comment: **Universal Generalization** would be **Universal Derivation** in your system, I think. In mine, it is called **Universal Introduction**. See step 7 in my proof, for example.

Comment: I see, for some reason that will not work for me and I have been suggested to do it by indirect derivation and quantifier negation -- any suggestions? I think its because of the free x

Comment: Aren’t you allowed to use Universal Derivation ? I do not have Elogic software so no way to test.

Comment: What is "alphabetic variance"?  If its what I suspect, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we rewrite the argument to avoid a clash of variables, one possible proof would be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You have Fa? Are you showing that? Because in my system you can't have free variables? Sorry I am really new to this.

Comment: You are welcome. I assume an arbitrary variable _a_ satisfies predicate **F**. How do you use Universal Instantiation in your system, then ?

Answer (score 0):

If your system does not allow universal derivation to use arbitrary variables other than that which will be bound to the universal quantifier (though it *should*), you could always make a derivation of (Ɐx (Gx)) → (Ɐx (Gx v Hx)) *before* you derive Ɐx (Fx → Ɐx (Gx v Hx)).

Thus avoiding conflicts caused by nesting the Show Ɐx (…) boxes

Also don't over complicate Show Gx v Hx with an indirect proof, when universal instantiation and addition will suffice.

```
 pr 1 Ɐx (Fx → Ɐx (Gx))
 1. Show Ɐx (Gx) → Ɐx (Gx v Hx)
 2. | Ɐx (Gx)                    ass
 3. | Show Ɐx (Gx v Hx)
 4. | | Show Gx v Hx
 5. | | Gx                       2 ui
 6. | | Gx v Hx                  5 add
 7. | Ɐx (Gx v Hx)               3 ud
 8. (Ɐx (Gx)) → (Ɐx (Gx v Hx))   1 cd
 9. Show Ɐx (Fx → Ɐx (Gx v Hx))
10. |  Show Fx → Ɐx (Gx v Hx)
11. |  |  Fx                     ass
12. |  |  Fx → Ɐx (Gx)           pr1 ui
13. |  |  Ɐx (Gx)                11,12 mp
14. |  |  Ɐx (Gx v Hx)           13, 8 mp
15. |  Fx → Ɐx (Gx v Hx)         10 cd
16. Ɐx (Fx → Ɐx (Gx v Hx))        9 ud
```